# Need to be able to update url in one location

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, url

I am new to programming and I need to update a large list of links and will need to do so every so often. I was instructed to put the links in one spot so that they would be easier to update next time. how should I do so? Do I use a resource file and if so what would be an example of how the reference would work.  For example the link http://wiki.kc.us.army.mil/jpeo/KCSS_System.... needs to be in one locations so it can be edited in the future.

```
function ShowHelp() {
    var pdfHelpWindow;
    pdfHelpWindow = window.open("https://wiki.kc.us.army.mil/jpeo/KCSS_System/User_Access#JPM_Access_POC", "", "");
    pdfHelpWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with c#?

Comment: @Recursor, this may require a c# code to read urls from file and build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I move all the list into some `xml` file like below

```
<links>
<link name="google">www.google.com</link>
<link name="stackoverflow">www.stackoverflow.com</link>
</links>
```

Then iterate each item and prepare a javascript array in a function `using C#`  and embed in the page using `<%= embedLinksJSArray() %>` in the page

The `embedLinksJSArray` will output the below in a page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allLinks={};
allLinks.google='www.google.com';//etc
</script>
```

Then

```
<script>    

function ShowHelp() {
    var pdfHelpWindow;
    pdfHelpWindow = window.open(allLinks.google, "", "");
    pdfHelpWindow.focus();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is create the separate class file as you mentioned. Make it a public static class (so that everything can reach it.

```
public static class URLResources
{
    public static void ShowHelp()
    {
        Process.Start("https://wiki.kc.us.army.mil/jpeo/KCSS_System/User_Access#JPM_Access_POC";
    }
...
}
```

That will open the default browser to the page you mentioned.

Comment: The code the OP provided is JavaScript.